# How to remove duplicated entries, and only keeping one entry per user per course

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, office365

Needed help here!

[image: Before]

Here, for example, the title (the title of a course), required date (the date they required to retake the course), and the completion date (the completion dates that a employee completed the course).

So, we have Title: B,C,D,F that are duplicated with an older completion date but without a "Required Date".

How can I remove duplicated course entries and only keeping the latest entry for each course and for each employee?

Similar to this:

[image: After]

Comment: what is there to indicate which is the latest entry ?

Comment: I would use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates then manually delete the older rows.

Comment: For example: Title D, have two completion entries, older entry was on 6/16/2014, and the latest entry was on 3/29/2017. @PeterH

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose which column would you use the duplicate formatting on? Would it be possible to do a conditional formatting to highlight multiple columns? like Emp# and Title?

Comment: @StevenChen you need a column that has JUST the completion date, Then you can create a pivot table and select all your columns, and the MAX of the completion date

Answer (score 0):

To work on your example, you can use the Advanced Filter:

Of course, if your real data has variations not seen in your example, all bets are off.

### Before

*note the formula for the filter*

[image]

### Filter Dialog Settings

*optionally set to copy results to a different location*

[image]

### Results

[image]

Comment: This mean I have to make the data into a table before I can use that formula?

Comment: @StevenChen Of course not.  If your data is not in a Table, then just replace the structured reference with the matching range reference,

Comment: This method works with just 1 employee data set, but if working with 6000 employee numbers, it filtered out all the blanks under required date. For example, with 1 employee data set, it worked like how it should be, but with multiple employee data, it will also filter out the "A" and "E" in your Results screenshot.

Comment: As I wrote *Of course, if your real data has variations not seen in your example, all bets are off.*  In other words, when you provide an example that is not representative of your real data, it is not surprising that a solution that works on your example might not work on your real data. Seems to be a frequent issue on this forum.

Comment: I do apologize for that, due to the size of the data, and I've tried to make it as simple as possible before making it even harder to explain the assistance I need. I thought this could be applied under more than one employee's data set.

With more than 6000 employee numbers
With 13 titles (not every employee has data for all 13 titles)
Please kindly assist....I have no where else to seek for assistance...

Comment: @StevenChen You could probably devise a `COUNTIFS` containing formula to take multiple employee numbers into account.

Comment: I have tried, the results are the same

Comment: @StevenChen As I indicated, my method works on the data you have provided. Since you are apparently unable to provide truly representative examples, I would suggest hiring a consultant who can examine your real data and provide a solution.